# Using #define from file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, macros

I got to know that to define a symbol visible in all files we can make an entry of `#define` in build of each project under `Conditional compilation symbols`.

Procedure to manually add it :

You can manually edit the .csproj file using Visual Studio's text editor.

1. Right click on your project in Solution Explorer.
2. Select Unload Project
3. Right click on your (unloaded) project in Solution Explorer.
4. Select Edit MyProject.csproj
5. Find the DefineConstants elements and edit your defined symbols there directly. The settings for Debug and Release configurations are in separate PropertyGroup elements.
6. Right click on your (unloaded) project in Solution Explorer.
7. Select Reload Project

But i want to add all my `#define` in one file and ask the project to refer to that file, in iOS we can achieve this by using prefix.pch file. can i do it in that way here for `WP8`

If yes how? if not apart from adding the #define to Conditional compilation symbols is there any other way that we can achieve this ?

Comment: You can also edit your `.csproj` file in your favorite text editor. (ie Notepad++) When you save it, VS will notice and prompt you to reload.

Comment: @paqogomez editing it in another text editor is not the question here

Comment: Correct, which is why its a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: In C# there is nothing like a C/C++ header file where you can put your `#define`s. You can only put them into your project file, but you don't need to do that by editing the project file. Instead put them into the *Conditional compilation symbols* textbox under *Build* in the project properties. Of course you can also have different build configurations with different sets of such symbols.

Comment: And note that in C# it is considered bad practice to use `#define` at all. There are alternatives like `const` declarations, `partial` classes, etc.

Comment: @Clemens thanks, i have around 50+ #define s, and also i am using Library project which has all code like pages,.cs etc... and the child app will only have the settings along with this #defines, so its hard to add and remove so, i wanted to have have something like prefix.pch like how its done in iOS , can you give me any suggestion something like that apart from me adding it to Conditional compilation symbols textbox under Build in the project properties

Comment: And "You use the const keyword to declare a constant field or a constant local. This keyword specifies that the value of the field or the local variable is constant, which means that it can't be modified"  it does not behave like macros skipping the code at runtime

Comment: That's why C# has partial classes and methods. Depending on your build configuration certains parts may be present or not.

Comment: How does that work can you please show me some example ?

Comment: However the doc says that it supports Conditional compilation symbols http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Please refer to the MSDN documentation and just google for "c# partial class". Basically you split your class into two or more partial declarations in separate code files. Then you create multiple Visual Studio projects and add only those code files to each that make up a certain build configuration. E.g. you may have MyClass1.cs and MyClass2.cs in one project and MyClass1.cs and MyClass3.cs in another. The source code [here](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) may give you an idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48755/discussion-between-user2056563-and-clemens)